# Java isFile(), isDirectory() without checking for existence

Tags: java, file, file-exists

I want to check if a given String is a file or a directory, i've tried the methods isFile() and isDirectory() of the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class but the problem is that if the directory or file doesn't exist these methods returns false, because as stated in the javadoc :

**isFile()** :

> true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists
>   and is a normal file; false otherwise

**isDirectory()** :

> true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists
>   and is a directory; false otherwise

Basically *i need two methods without the exist clause* ...

So i want to test if the given string complies to a directory format or complies to a file format, in a multiplatform context (so, should work on Windows, Linux and Mac Os X).

Does exist some library that provide these methods ? What could be the best implementation of these methods ?

**UPDATE**

In the case of a string that could be both(without extension) by default should be identified as directory, if a file with that path does not exist.

Comment: Apache commons.io could help you. Maybe using FileUtils.sizeof() or something like that...

Comment: How will Java know if a pathname pointing to something that doesn't exist is a file or a directory if there's nothing there? There's no pathname format to determine if something is a file or directory across all OSes.

Comment: What you want is not possible, there is no difference between a file and a directory unless it actually exists in the file system (and has the necessary attributes the OS provides) Extensions and the like might be just your own assumption. Side note: extension doesn't exist either nowadays, it is an old, old artifact coming from DOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you know what you want, according to your update: if the path doesn't exist and the path has an extension it's a file, if it doesn't it's a directory. Something like this would suffice:

```java
private boolean isPathDirectory(String myPath) {
    File test = new File(myPath);

    // check if the file/directory is already there
    if (!test.exists()) {
        // see if the file portion it doesn't have an extension
        return test.getName().lastIndexOf('.') == -1;
    } else {
        // see if the path that's already in place is a file or directory
        return test.isDirectory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> So i want to test if the given string complies to a directory format or complies to a file format, in a multiplatform context (so, should work on Windows, Linux and Mac Os X).

In Windows, a directory can have an extension and a file is not required to have an extension.  So, you can't tell just by looking at the string.

If you enforce a rule that a directory doesn't have an extension, and a file always has an extension, then you can determine the difference between a directory and a file by looking for an extension.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just wrap them in a call to [`File#exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)?

```
File file = new File(...);
if (file.exists()) {

    // call isFile() or isDirectory()

}
```

By doing that, you've effectively negated the "exists" portion of `isFile()` and `isDirectory()`, since you're guaranteed that it does exist.

---

It's also possible that I've misunderstood what you're asking here. Given the second part of your question, are you trying to use `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` on non-existent files to see if they *look like* they're files or directories?

If so, that's going to be tough to do with the `File` API (and tough to do in general). If `/foo/bar/baz` doesn't exist, it's not possible to determine whether it's a file or a directory. It could be either.

Comment: "It could be either." And it could be neither.

Comment: In the case of a string that could be both(without extension) by default should be identified as directory, if a file with that path does not exist.

Comment: @aleroot - That's something that your own business logic will have to enforce, since file extensions are mostly based on convention and don't really matter to most filesystems.

Comment: "you're guaranteed that it does exist" ... unless some other process has deleted the file/directory in between the call to file.exists() and isFile().  Unlikely, perhaps, but possible.

Comment: @BrianRogers, it can be the same process, just another thread.

Comment: @bestsss - True; same idea though.

Answer (score 0):

There are rules for what is invalid in a file and/or folder name.  For example, Windows doesn't allow `*`, `?`, and a few other characters.  Based on what's invalid, you could build a `regex` expression or some other process/checking system to see if it *looks like* a file or folder.

This could get complex as you want it to work for many different OS's.  Also, as previously posted, there would be no way to tell a file from a folder unless you artificially enforced a convention.  For example, directories must end in a front-slash `/` in Windows.

Having the `IF EXISTS` check first would help.  If `IF EXISTS = true`, then running the existing `File.isDirectory()` or `File.isFile()` code would simplify a lot of this.  You would only have to write code for when IF EXISTS = false.